# Flutter: Provider error when mocking stream within a Mock

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a bloc object which contains a stream:

```
Bloc {
  final _controller = StreamController<MainEvents>.broadcast();

  Stream<MainEvents> get stream => _controller.stream;
}
```

I'm trying to mock this object in order to do another test using [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito):

```
Bloc bloc = Bloc();

final _controller = StreamController<MainEvents>.broadcast();
when(mainBloc.stream).thenAnswer((_) => _controller.stream);
```

Then I construct a test widget providing this bloc via [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package:

```
testWidget = MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider<Bloc>.value(value: bloc)
  ],
  child: Something(),
);
```

But when I execute the test, this provider constructions fails with the error:

> The following assertion was thrown building Provider(dirty,
>   state:
>   _DelegateWidgetState#9ee17): Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream (Bloc).
>
> This is likely a mistake, as Provider will not automatically update
>   dependents when Bloc is updated. Instead, consider changing Provider
>   for more specific implementation that handles the update mecanism,
>   such as:
>
> - ListenableProvider
> - ChangeNotifierProvider
> - ValueListenableProvider
> - StreamProvider

The app works ok but the test fails, any help?

Comment: Either the BLoC implementation you gave is not the real one, of there's nothing in the code you gave that can cause an issue

Comment: @RémiRousselet why you say that the bloc implementation is not the real one?

Comment: It is relevant. The exception says that your BLoC class is a stream/listenable, but your code snippet says otherwise

Comment: It does matter. Because the exception says that your Bloc class is a stream/listenable when your snippet says otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was caused by the Provider you're trying to use on `MultiProvider.providers`. As mentioned in the logs, you may need to consider changing Provider to a more specific implementation.

Consider modifying the provider to `ListenableProvider` and see if it fits your use case.

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ListenableProvider<Bloc>.value(value: bloc)
  ],
  ...
)
```